# Android hide/show headers on condition from settings activity

Tags: android

I am working on an android project. I am doing work on settings. I want to show/hide headers from settings activity on condition. i.e. hide/show some headers when user is logged in or logged out.
This is my pref_headers file:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header
    android:id="@+id/head_server"
    android:fragment="com.example.imran.myapp.SettingsActivity$MyPrefs"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
    android:title="Server Settings" />
</preference-headers>
```

I have googled alot about this but couldn't find a way. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option is to create two different xml preference headers and display one depending on the condition.

Comment: any other? there is another option for me but i don't want that. Since i have i have separate login page activity and separate activity opens when user successfully logs in. So I can create separate settings activity for login activity and so for other activity. I don't want this, but may be i will do this when i have no other options.

Comment: You don't need to create two different activities. Just when you implement the method `onBuildHeaders()` you choose one or other xml. Just pass a bundle when user successfully logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove headers, as such:

Here's a way to hide a debug header, for example, in case we are in debug mode:

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(final List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences_headers, target);
    if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        for (Iterator<Header> iterator = target.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            final Header header = iterator.next();
            if (header.id == R.id.debug) {
                iterator.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This assumed you have id for the header, as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:id="@+id/debug"
        android:fragment="..." android:icon="..."
        android:title="Debug"/>
```

If you wish to cause it to call `onBuildHeaders` again, with a new list, call `invalidateHeaders();`